# Issue retrieving pfobject data from pointer in Parse.com

Tags: ios, nsarray, parse-platform

I'm having issues getting data from the pointers within objects I get from from my parse query. I use the include key on the query, but having issues getting the include key information from the returned objects array. I created a for loop to iterate over the results but not sure how to store them back into an array. Here's my code below:

```
- (void) loadUsersPFUserIsFollowing
    {


        //Retrieving PFUser Curren Users followers and storing in Array
        PFQuery *queryFollowingCount = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
        [queryFollowingCount whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"follow"];
        [queryFollowingCount whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

        //Access the the user following informatioin
        [queryFollowingCount includeKey:@"toUser"];

        //[queryFollowingCount setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];

        [queryFollowingCount findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            [HUD hide:YES];
            if (!error) {

               searchResultsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];            

               NSLog(@"%@", objects);

                for (PFObject * postObject in objects) {

                   PFObject *postAuthor = [postObject objectForKey:@"toUser"][@"username"];



                    NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);
                }

                  [self.tableView reloadData];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (PFObject * postObject in objects) {
     PFObject *postAuthor = [postObject objectForKey:@"toUser"][@"username"];

     NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);
}
```

By default, when fetching an object, related PFObjects are not fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched like so:

```
for (PFObject * postObject in objects) {

     //Im assuming in your code, postObject is either nil or it's there but it's values are nil except its objectId. We need to fetch this object. 
     [postObject fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){

          PFObject *postAuthor = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"][@"username"];

          NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);

         [self.tableView reloadData];

      }];
}
```

Comment: ahhhh gotcha! I have a search implemented that will filter through the returned results. I'm trying to store each fetch pfobject into an array so that I can filter through the results using a search , but I see the fetchIf.. only returns one object. Or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Your initial query `queryFollowingCount` will return the top level object and it's properties. The pointers to other objects are there but faulted, so it's just a bunch of `objectId`s of the `PFObjects` your top level object is pointing to. You have to fetch each one of those objects you point to independently.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll have to refine my query to a compound query to get the results I'm looking for